# Django vs MySQL uuid

Tags: python, mysql, django, uuid

Django noob here

I have created a model using

```
customer_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

After migrating the model to MySQL, I tried to add data into mysql using

```
insert into customer_customer (customer_id, ...) values (uuid(), ...)
```

The data gets inserted properly in MySQL with a unique code, however, when I try to display this via Django admin tool (this table feeds into a property for users), it throws a badly formatted uuid error.

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/uuid.py", line 134, in __init__
raise ValueError('badly formed hexadecimal UUID string')
ValueError: badly formed hexadecimal UUID string
```

Please discuss if there is another way of creating seed data directly in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

> A field for storing universally unique identifiers. Uses Python’s UUID
>   class. When used on PostgreSQL, this stores in a uuid datatype,
>   otherwise in a char(32).

So with MySQL django handles the uuid, and manages the field as Char32. You can't use native MySQL uuid.

If you have to create uuid **from the MySQL side**, use a CharField in django model, and populate it:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    fld = models.CharField(max_length=36)
```

Then when saving:

```
import uuid
MyModel.fld = str(uuid.uuid4())
```

As a default:

```
fld = models.CharField(max_length=36, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

Comment: Thanks Aviah for your response. I was hoping to keep the Django model as is, but be able to add some records in MySQL that will not break Django. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: No. What is your scenario for adding from MySQL?

Comment: Lambda's cannot be serialized, so this will prevent you from creating any migrations for this model. You can use a proper function definition and pass that function instead, or you can probably even get away with passing `uuid.uuid4` and letting the field handle the conversion to `str`.

Comment: I have records from a previous system that I need to load into the new model - I would rather new keys be created here for go-forward solution. Thanks.

Comment: So use the answer. The django UUID field is using uuid.UUID which is a 32 chars UUID. MySQL uses the 36 chars uuid. It's OK to use a string as I suggested, basically uuid is a string, and when you use uuid.uuid4 you get all the uuid functionality

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
insert into customer_customer (customer_id, ...) values (Replace(uuid(),'-',''), ...)
```

then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation states that if you use a MySQL database, Django will store a string (char32):

> UUIDField.
> A field for storing universally unique identifiers. Uses Python’s UUID class. When used on PostgreSQL, this stores in a uuid datatype, otherwise in a char(32).

Python's uuid module gives you the following options to generate UUIDs:

```
>>> import uuid

>>> uuid.uuid4()
UUID('bd65600d-8669-4903-8a14-af88203add38')

>>> str(uuid.uuid4())
'f50ec0b7-f960-400d-91f0-c42a6d44e3d0'

>>> uuid.uuid4().hex
'9fe2c4e93f654fdbb24c02b15259716c'
```

In your case (using uuid4 as default in the Django module), you will need to use the "UUID.uuid4().hex" option in order to save the UUID as a string, just like Django would save it in your MySql database.